# Why is the Support Vector Regressor predicting all the same numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying a new approach to regression and have always been interested in using Support Vector Machines to do it. The problem is that I'm feeding it training data so it can predict on test data. When it predicts on the training data, it predicts like the following-

```
array([ 8.00000947,  8.10000947,  7.90000947,  8.40000947,  8.50000947,
        8.10000947,  7.90000947,  8.20000947,  8.40000947,  8.20000948,
        8.40000948,  8.40000947,  8.00000947,  8.10000947,  8.50000948,
        8.40000947,  8.60000947,  8.40000948,  8.40000948,  8.00000947,
        8.50000948,  8.30000948,  7.99922823, ...
```

But, when I predict on the test data, it predicts like so-

```
array([ 7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,
        7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,
        7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697, ...
```

The code is as follows-

```
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

df = pd.read_excel('featureset.xlsx')
df.shape
(280, 23)

cols = pd.factorize(df.columns)
X= df
X.columns = cols[0]
Y.columns = [51]

X_train = X[:196]
X_test = X[196:]
y_train = Y[:196]
y_test = Y[196:]

y_train.shape
(196L,)

y_test.shape
(84L,)

clf = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, degree=2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Thus, resulting in

```
array([ 7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697,  7.92969697, ...
```

Comment: If this is all your code, it looks like you're X_test contains many copies of the same data item (X_test[i]==X_test[j])

Comment: Since X_train == y_train, you are training the model to map x to x.